# How to make a query on a SOAP webservice using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I need to make a query on a SOAP webservice using PHP, but I need to send this "authentication". How do I make this request?

Url of webservice: http://externo.detran.es.gov.br/WSBioHMLG/Monitoramento/WsAulasPraticas.svc?wsdl

Documentation:

```
//Assinatura
ConsultarSituacaoInstrutorPraticoRetorno ConsultaSituacaoInstrutorPratico( 
ConsultarSituacaoInstrutorPraticoEnvio model, UsuarioModel usuario)

Parâmetros de Envio
Classe com as informações para pesquisa da situação do Instrutor Prático 
class ConsultarSituacaoInstrutorPraticoEnvio : ConsultarSituacaoDadosEnvio
{
    CPF do instrutor/ Obrigatório 
    decimal CpfInstrutor
}
Classe base de dados de pesquisa de situação
class ConsultarSituacaoDadosEnvio : MonitoramentoAulaPraticaBase
{
    //CNPJ do CFC / Obrigatório 
    decimal CnpjCfc
}
class MonitoramentoAulaPraticaBase
{
    //Login e senha da empresa de monitoramento credenciada. 
    //Consiste de um campo de login e senha / Obrigatório 
    MonitAulaPraticaHeader UsuarioProdest
}
```

I call the method :

```
$requestParams = array(         
    'model' => array(
        'Categoria' => "A",
        'CpfInstrutor' => 123456789
    ),
    'usuario' => array(
        'Login' => "User",
        'Senha' => "******"         
    )
);
                    
$result = $client->__soapCall('ConsultaSituacaoInstrutorPratico', array($requestParams));
```

But return "login/password is missing".

Ps.: Sorry my English, I used the translator.

Ps. 2: I'm using PHP SOAPClient.

Where I have doubts:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Biometria.MonitoramentoAulasPraticas" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Biometria.MonitoramentoAulasPraticas">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ComponentModel"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
<xs:complexType name="MonitAulaPraticaHeader">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ComponentModel" name="PropertyChanged" nillable="true" type="q1:PropertyChangedEventHandler"/>
        <xs:element xmlns:q2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" name="anyAttrField" nillable="true" type="q2:ArrayOfArrayOfanyType"/>
            <xs:element name="loginField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="senhaField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="MonitAulaPraticaHeader" nillable="true" type="tns:MonitAulaPraticaHeader"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Using the [PHP SoapClient](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.construct.php) you have two options to connect to a service, with a [.wsdl formatted xml](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_wsdl.asp) file - this xml does not seems to be a wsdl - or using an URL. You can find examples in the PHP manual.

Comment: Alright, you have your wsdl file in remote source, but I still don't understand what you try to achieve with this xml you posted. You can authenticate in soap with a username/password.

Comment: @Derenir I edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create the client connection:

```
$wsdl = "http://externo.detran.es.gov.br/WSBioHMLG/Monitoramento/WsAulasPraticas.svc?wsdl";
//  SOAP connector config
$soap_config = array(
    'soap_version'      => SOAP_1_1,
    'authentication'    => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
    'login'             => 'username',
    'password'          => 'password',
    
);

//  Connect to soap interface
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soap_config);
```

And then you can call the SOAP method:

```
$requestParams = array(
    'model' => array(
        'Categoria' => "A",
        'CpfInstrutor' => 123456789
    ),
    'usuario' => array(
        'Login' => "User",
        'Senha' => "******"
    )
);

$result = $soap->ConsultaSituacaoInstrutorPratico($requestParams);
```